# How to listen on same port, separate address using spice from libvirt?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, libvirt, spice

### Background info

#### On the host

I have a virtual bridge setup, and have two static IPs configured: `10.0.3.1/16` and `10.0.3.2/16`.

The host is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and is up-to-date at the time of this post.

#### For the VMs

**VM 1** is set up to listen on `10.0.3.1` port `5900`. When I `sudo virsh start vm1`, it starts up correctly and I can connect to it.

It's libvirt config looks like this:

```
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='10.0.3.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='10.0.3.1'/>
      <image compression='auto_lz'/>
    </graphics>
```

**VM 2** is set up to listen on `10.0.3.2` port `5900`:

```
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='10.0.3.2'>
      <listen type='address' address='10.0.3.2'/>
      <image compression='auto_lz'/>
    </graphics>
```

When I `sudo virsh start vm2` I get an error:

```
error: Failed to start domain vm2
error: internal error: Failed to reserve port 5900
```

`sudo netstat -nltp` shows the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:5900           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32092/qemu-system-x
```

### What do I need?

I would like to use different IPs for each VM, and use the same 5900 port, but I am getting these errors saying that the port is already bound (which it is, just on a different address).

How can I get it to use the same port but on a different address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a libvirt bug. It checks for port conflicts using `0.0.0.0`, without taking into account the listen address.

You can probably work around it by using qemu commandline passthrough to pass a valid `-spice` arg to qemu that libvirt won't look at. Not very friendly but it's an option if you just want to get something working

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's a bug and I'm not crazy. If I wanted to submit a bug, any chance you know where I could do that for libvirt?

Comment: bugzilla.redhat.com, more info here: https://libvirt.org/bugs.html

Comment: Bug submitted: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1751969